# Is it safe to use overlay as new VM from QCOW2 image for multiple users?

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, openstack, qcow2

As title states, is it safe to give overlay of same image to multiple different users? From security standpoint, do they have access to other users data? Can any user corrupt/change base image or manipulate other user VM?

If it's not safe, is there any other solution to save disk space and fast generate/dispose VMs ?

VMs do not need to preserve any data as they are purged after shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works.  The VM has read access to the shared base image and write access their private overlay and nothing else.  So they can't corrupt the base image and they can't see what other VMs are doing.